# How to close an application without animation

Tags: java, android

I need to have an invisible button that close my application but without the animation displaying that an application was closed.

The transition must be seemless because the app will be displaying a screenshot of phone's home page and it must look likes there were no application opened when the user touch the button.

I tried removing activity animations in theme and in code but there is still an animation when the app close.

Is it possible ? How ?

Comment: Even without animation, a screen disappearing suddenly will definitely alarm the user, it might be better if you leave it with some graceful animation rather.
What you are trying to do looks more like a phishing page for an app.

Comment: I am also interested in your idea, but soon after I read the question I think its impossible that way. But I am thinking what about a DialogActivity with the dialog filling the screen?? Its animation does not seem so obvious like of a normal activity. @JulianCDC

Comment: I already tried using a DialogActivity but there is still an animation and I really need to have no animation @Xenolion

Comment: Mmmh I am running out of Ideas if you have already tried that...Different Android Version have different swags of Animation, Different Manufacturers have different swags of Animation. So if you can `startActivity( Activityof the Phone Home Launcher)` and set your own Activity Transition to make it look like it is just like a slide.... And the user was browsing the Home....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible, as that is something that is dealt with on an OS level. You could intentionally crash the app by throwing an uncaught exception or something like that, but then you will get a dialog showing that it indeed crashed.

I think you need to go back to the drawing board with coming up with a good prank. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe be you can try this:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

You need invoke `overridePendingTransition(0,0)` after `finish` that will disable transition animation